# android UiTestAutomationBridge null root node returned

Tags: androidviewclient

I get below error when doing vc.dump call.  It goes fine at times and randomly fails with this error.

ERROR: Offending XML:
u'ERROR: null root node returned by UiTestAutomationBridge.\r\n'
LoginTest failure
(ExpatError('syntax error: line 1, column 0',),)

I am not sure if its emulator, device, AOSP unanimator jar or androidviewclient causing it.

I think it mostly happens when a dialog is shown on screen.

Regards,

Miten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an UiAutomator error. Instead of returning a valid XML containing the View dump it returns the error message:

```
'ERROR: null root node returned by UiTestAutomationBridge.\r\n'
```

Not an **AndroidViewClient** issue.

Comment: What can we do in this case? As we need to create the XML at any cost but with this error this is not possible so is there any way to do so?